# Run two session of excel with two different PID

Tags: excel, pid

I would like to open 2 excel sessions to run macros in parallel.

On some occasion, while executing a macro, I have opened excel normally and it has opened it in a different session and I have been able to execute another macro in parallel. My intention is to force this situation.

Thanks!

Best regards!

Comment: I tryed with open excel from taskbar with "Alt" botton, and not work

Comment: Why not simply copy the file and run the second macro? And if the data affects one macro on the other, how do you plan to run both at the same time?

Comment: They can run in parallel, because data from one macro does not affect another. For example, I have a file that calculates sales with base file A and another file that also calculates sales with base file B. These files could be executed in parallel because they have nothing to do with each other.